# Optimizing a loop extracting substrings from a field based on another field

Tags: python, performance, optimization, pandas

I am dealing with large dataset (4 million by 4). The first column is name identifier and many rows have the same name. The second column is a position, starting at -6 and going always up until a new identifier is met, then it starts counting again. The third column is a random number, not important here. The fourth column is a long sequence of numbers, like a long bar code. The data looks a bit like this:

```
YKLOI    -6    01    123456789012345678901234
YKLOI    -5    25    123456789012345678901234
YKLOI    -4    05    123456789012345678901234
YKLOI    -3    75    123456789012345678901234
YKLOI    -2    83    123456789012345678901234
YKLOI    -1    05    123456789012345678901234
YKLOI     0    34    123456789012345678901234
YKLOI     1    28    123456789012345678901234
YKLJW    -6    87    569845874254658425485
YKLJW    -5    87    569845874254658425485
...
```

And I would like to make it look like this:

```
YKLOI    -6    01    123   #puts 1st triplet in position -6
YKLOI    -5    25    456   #puts 2nd triplet in position -5
YKLOI    -4    05    789   #puts 3rd triplet in position -4
YKLOI    -3    75    012   #puts 4th triplet in position -3
YKLOI    -2    83    345                ...
YKLOI    -1    05    678
YKLOI     0    34    901
YKLOI     1    28    234   #puts last triplet in the last position
YKLJW    -6    87    569   #puts 1st triplet in position -6
YKLJW    -5    87    845   #puts 2nd triplet in position -5
...
```

The length on what is in the fourth column varies a lot, but numbers on the second column are always in sequence.

The code below is the one that I got that is actually doing the job, but it is taking forever to do it. As of now, it is running for almost 18 hours and it is barely over line 1 million.

I tried a few alternatives such as only building a map if the names in the first column in sequential rows are different, but this just adds a statement into it and makes the code much slower.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to improve the performance for this task?

```
import pandas as pd

#imports data
d = pd.read_csv('INPUT_FILE', sep='\t') 

#acknowledges that data was imported
print "Import Okay" 

#sets output path
output='OUTPUT_FILE' 

#loops from the first row till the end
for z in xrange(0,len(d)-1): 

    #goes to the fourth column, split the content every 3 characters and creates 
    #a list of these triplets.
    mop=map(''.join, zip(*[iter(d.loc[z][3])]*3)) 

    #substitutes the content of the fourth column in the z line by the triplet in 
    #the z+6 positon
    d.ix[z,3] = mop[int(d.loc[z][1])+6]

    #writes the new z line into the output file
    d.loc[[z]].to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=False, index=False, mode='a')

#acknowledges that the code is through
print "Done"
```

Comment: Probably the only way of making your program much more efficient is to rewrite it in more efficient programming language. You will gain from 10x to 100x or more in speed. It is well known that Python is not a particularly efficient language.

Comment: The looping is terribly inefficient.  Is the data in the last column a string or a long integer?

Comment: @Renzo - So, once a Python program is written, there's no way to make it any faster other than rewriting it in a different language? Is your Python IDE a stone tablet?

Comment: @Renzo -  It is well known that many people do not understand how to use Python efficiently.

Comment: @Alexander, it is perfectly true that many people have problems in optimizing Python code, and that there is in general a lot of space to improve *any* program in *any* language. But I think it is also true that many people use the wrong tool for a certain job. If the OP says “it is taking forever”, then in my opinion only two things can really improve this situation: either change radically the algorithm, reducing its complexity, or change the language and use one compiled in machine code. If the answer(s) given reduce the complexity, the problem is solved. Otherwise...

Comment: @Alexander - Just to let you know, it is a long string, as I also have a new letters scattered here and there.

Comment: @Renzo - I have the limitation that the codes needs to be in python, sqlite or bash, as this is the part of an ongoing pipeline. But just out of curiosity, which language you think would speed up the task?

And for references, yeah, it is still running and it is taking forever!

Comment: A typical language which is compiled to machine code is C or C++, but there are many others (for performances comparisons see for instance [this](https://attractivechaos.github.io/plb/) and [this](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org). But you could also still use Python and call for the inner loop a C function (see [this](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html)). SQLite is another good alternative. But everything depends if you will use this algorithm only once or many times, if you have similar problems to solve, etc.

Comment: @Renzo - the performance comparison is very interesting. I will really look into it more carefully now - making sure that I am at least using the best language for the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two easy changes to start with.  One, don't incrementally write the output file, it adds a lot of unnecessary overhead, and is your biggest problem by far.

Second, you seem to be going through a lot of steps to pull out the triplet.  Something like this would be more efficient, and the `.apply` removes some of the looping overhead.

```
def triplet(row):
    loc = (row[1] + 6) * 3
    return row[3][loc:loc+3]

d[3] = d.apply(triplet, axis=1)

# save the whole file once
d.to_csv(output2, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: Indeed the constant saving is a drag. Only that already helped, now I only take 3s per loop instead of 15s. But this function is somehow not working - either I am doing something wrong (likely!) or it actually increases the loop cycle to 8s. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your code that's not working or the error you get?  Keep in mind that `.apply` is vectorized, it shouldn't be used in a loop, just once.  You should see another significant speedup (I was getting 20-100x depending on size of the data).

Comment: I just redid it now and somehow it had run so fast that I didn't see the result at first - this adds a new column instead of replacing it and given the size one can easily get lost in it.

But it works like a charm! All the data was processed in under 1 minute. I am shocked how fast it was. Thanks a lot.